# Should we use tuple or list for index_together

Tags: python, django

For `index_together`, I was wondering, should I use `tuple` or `list`, as both seems workable.

### tuple

```
class ApiMonthlyUsage(models.Model):
    month = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    count = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        index_together = (
            ('month', 'user'),
        )
```

### list

```
class ApiMonthlyUsage(models.Model):
    month = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    count = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        index_together = [
            ['month', 'user'],
        ]
```

Comment: The [documentation uses lists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#index-together), but I can't see why a mutable sequence would be required. If tuples work, stick with those.

Comment: You should use tuple for lists that will not change. Tuples are faster tyan arrays, but are immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only objective answer here is to give you a list of the common arguments each way:

- *list*: The Django docs and samples use lists. Consistency with a framework—especially one that has relatively strong idioms that often differ from the rest of the Python world—is worth something.
- *tuple*: The sequence is immutable. Mutability is the only behavioral difference between lists and tuples, so (at least according to many Python developers, including many of the core/stdlib devs), it’s usually the most sensible way to pick between them.
- *list*: The paradigm use for tuples is a fixed number of values where each position has a specific type/semantics, so (at least according to many Python developers, including Guido and some of the other core/stdlib developers) it’s clearer to use a list when you want an arbitrary-length homogenous sequence.
- *tuple*: Tuples use slightly less memory and are occasionally faster, although neither is likely to be at all relevant here.

But it’s up to you to decide how much you agree with each of these and how much weight to give them.

But really, as long as you pick one or the other and use it consistently in your project, your code will be perfectly readable to any other Python developer, so I wouldn’t stress too much. If you really can’t decide, flip a coin and get on with it.